# I Have 2 DropDownList in a View, But I dont Received the selected Values In a controller HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this MVC Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KPI", "KPI", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "formulario" }))
                {
                    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i>Año</i>
                            </div>
                            @Html.DropDownList("AnosList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AnosList"], new { @class = "form-control pull-right", @id = "AnosListId", @style = "color:black;" })        
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i>Mes</i>
                            </div>
                            @Html.DropDownList("Meses", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Meses"], new { @class = "form-control pull-right", @id = "MesId", @style = "color:black;" })
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->
                    </div><!-- /.form group -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>  Buscar</button>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                }
```

Like at you see in the view two DropDownList, But i dont received the selected values en

> HTTPPOST

Please help me, here you can see the HTML in a web explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLsuV.jpg)

And I try to receive in a controler like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult KPI(string AnosListId, string MesId)
        {
          //Do Something here with the values 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method parameter name should match with the HTML element **name** attribute value.

Your current code generates 2 select element with names "AnosList" and "Meses"

So fix your action method parameter name.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KPI(string AnosList, string Meses)
{
     //Do Something here with the values 
}
```

When the form is submitted, the browser will send the element value with the element name.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought the Post Controller receives the id of the element not the name. Now this works fine. Regards from Dominican Republic.